# Nested Countif array formula referencing multiple workbooks and multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

I'm creating a report that references employee information from multiple external workbooks.  In these workbooks, there is information in two columns that I am interested in (Active-Inactive and Status).  Is there a formula that I can use to count only occurrences where information in the Active-Inactive column="Active" AND information in the Status column="Overdue" (i.e only return a count if an employee shows as "Active" AND "Overdue"?

Comment: COUNTIFS() does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNTIFS` doesn't work with closed workbooks, you can possibly use `SUMPRODUCT` like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(([Book1]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1000="Active")*([Book1]Sheet1!$B$1:$B$1000="Overdue"))`

Change workbook/sheet names and column references as required

For data with error values you can use this array formula:

`=SUM(IFERROR(([Book1]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1000="Active")*([Book1]Sheet1!$B$1:$B$1000="Overdue"),0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

easiest to set up with the external workbook open - if you point to the ranges you can get the correct syntax - then when you close external workbook you'll get the full path

Comment: I tried the above suggestion but get an #N/A message.  I think this is because the source data has some cells with #N/A in it because they are placeholders for employees should the company hire more employees.  Unfortunately, I can't edit the source document to remove the #N/As.  Is there another solution?

Comment: `COUNTIFS` will ignore error values but `SUMPRODUCT` doesn't do that - you can use a slightly amended version with `IFERROR`, see my edited answer